# Error: basic_string::_S_create, (trying to use .ecw files)

Tags: qgis, ecw

I have a problem, after resolving my problem with: .ecw is not a supported data file. I am in a new one. When I try to load an .ecw  file in QGIS it says: basic_string::_S_create